# Mark of the Web doesn't allow jquery to read local files in windows 8 machine

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-8, internet-explorer-10

I am creating a web page that a user can view locally(i.e.) file:// protocol. When i open in IE10 on windows 8 machine it shows 'Allow Blocked content' alert. After press Allow blocked content the page can load local js files.

To remove the 'Allow Blocked content' popup i added the follwing Mark of the Web

`<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->`

Now it doesn't show the 'Allow blocked content' alert. But local js files are not loaded through jquery.

Please take a look at my code

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>       
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() 
        {
               $.getScript('js/loadImages.js',function(){
               alert(1);
           });
        });
    </script>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY style="margin:0px; padding: 0px;">
       <!-- some stuff -->
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

What is wrong with my code? or how to acheive both removing 'Allow Blocked Content' alert and read local files via jquery ?

Comment: i'd be surprised you could bypass browser's security restriction just using javascript

Comment: As soon as you use `file:///`, you should expect things not to work. The number of hoops you're going to have to jump through to get this working, I would say you'd be better off giving up and just installing a localhost web server.

Comment: The mark of the web should come after the doctype declaration not before. Don't know if that will help you do what you want or not but it should be that way around.